# How to READ, SPLITLINES and FILTER TXT file, without create a new txt file

Tags: python, python-3.x

i need read, split and filter txt file ( list of domain site), i have try but still get error or problem.

Thanks so much for any help!

Ps. maybe "100%" my code is wrong, but i am just start learn python max 3 weeks.

```
            my_List = str(input_List(f"{R}\n   Your List --> : "))
            head, tail = os.path.split(my_List)
            if (not os.path.isfile(my_List)):
                print(f"{AA}\n   {current_timesst} {CC}{Y}[!] File does not exist!\n".format(my_List))
                pass
            out_of_scope = ['whm.','cpanel.','cpcalendars.','webmail.','webdisk.','mail.','cpcontacts.','ftp.','sftp.','smtp.','pop.','pop3.','localhost.','hostmaster.','imap.','autoconfig.','autodiscover.']
            for out in out_of_scope:
                out_of_scope = out

            url_list = open(my_List).read().splitlines()
            url_list = []
            for line in url_list:
                for out_of_scope in out:
                    if out_of_scope in line:
                        url_list.append(line)

            
            num_list=sum(1 for line in open(head+"\\"+tail)) " HERE NEED RECALCULATE LINE -OUT_OF -SCOPE, HOW TO DO IT "
```

Answer (score 0):

I think i have get a solution, is correct right ?

```
            my_List  = str(input_List(f"{R}\n   Your List --> : "))
            head, tail = os.path.split(my_List)
            if (not os.path.isfile(my_List)):
                print(f"{AA}\n   {current_timesst} {CC}{Y}[!] File does not exist!\n".format(my_List))
                pass
            url_list = open(my_List).read().splitlines()
            out_of_scope=['whm.','cpanel.','cpcalendars.','webmail.','webdisk.','mail.','cpcontacts.','ftp.','sftp.','smtp.','pop.','pop3.','localhost.','hostmaster.','imap.','autoconfig.','autodiscover.']               
            filter_data = [x for x in url_list if
                all(y not in x for y in out_of_scope)]
            url_list = filter_data
```